# Next.js, Firebase, Unhandled Runtime Error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'initializeApp' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, next.js

I have no idea why this error happens... but I suspect this file causes something??
Especially, `firebaseAuth={getAuth(app)}` might be a problem.
Before that, `const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);` is defined in `"../firebase/firebase"`

```
import React from "react";
import StyledFirebaseAuth from "react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth";
import { app } from "../firebase/firebase";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, EmailAuthProvider, GoogleAuthProvider, GithubAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

// Configure FirebaseUI.
const uiConfig = {
  signInFlow: 'popup',
  signInSuccessUrl: "/",
  signInOptions: [
    EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
  ],
};

export default function SignInScreen() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>PolygonHR Login</h1>
      <p>Please sign-in:</p>
      <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={getAuth(app)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that this library called "react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth", which I use above, support firebase version 8.x.x instead of v9 above, so this is why this error message in title has been shown.

To fix this,

1. downgrade and adjust firebase version that the library requires
2. or switch the library with another one to display authentication button.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

With new version of Firebase the syntax to import is changed.
Try with this:
`import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';`
I suggest you to read this post to identify and fix other problem in your app.
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/08/the-new-firebase-js-sdk-now-ga.html

Comment: Give me an up if my comment help you!

Comment: Yes gave it to you, the way how import it is the very problem, but this is caused by external library instead of my own code though... This is why it was hard to find it.